# List Comprehension.. am I crazy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a list of phone numbers

```
phone_numbers = [000-000-0000, 000-000-0000, 000-000-0000]


for number in phone_numbers:
   x = list(filter(str.isdigit, number.strip()))
   t = "".join(x)
```

Gives me my desired outcome of `0000000000`

Is it possible to use list comprehension for this purpose or am I completely off?

`[list(filter(str.isdigit, x.strip())) for x in phone_numbers]`

Comment: Btw do you realize that you got list of *results* of subtraction rather than phone numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use list comprehension.

```
["".join(filter(str.isdigit, number.strip())) for number in phone_numbers]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some solutions,

```
import re

phone_numbers = ["000-000-0000", "000-000-0000", "000-000-0000"]

>>> ["".join(re.findall("\d+", p)) for p in phone_numbers]

['0000000000', '0000000000', '0000000000']
```

**OR**

```
>>> ["".join(x for x in p if x.isdigit()) for p in phone_numbers]

['0000000000', '0000000000', '0000000000']
```